# Same word but different unicode characters

Tags: python, mongodb, unicode

I built a question answering application in terms of restaurants in Vietnam using Python on Windows. To write Vietnamese characters I need to use Unicode.
First, I clone data from TripAdvisor website which used HTML charset=utf-8 and build my Mongo database. A city named "đà nẵng" in TripAdvisor has a code:

```
>>> print repr("đà nẵng")     # from tripadvisor website 
>>> '\xc4\x91a\xcc\x80 n\xc4\x83\xcc\x83ng'
```

However, when I query from Firefox's address bar, the city "đà nẵng" has a different code:

```
>>> print repr("đà nẵng")   # Firefox's address bar
>>> '\xc4\x91\xc3\xa0 n\xe1\xba\xb5ng'
```

That is a reason why I can not find that city in my database. I try to write this city name on notepad++ and got the same result as using Firefox's address bar

```
>>> print repr("đà nẵng")   # notepad++ using 'Encoding UTF-8'
>>> '\xc4\x91\xc3\xa0 n\xe1\xba\xb5ng'
```

Is there any way to convert between two types of code?
Or is there any way to match the city name "đà nẵng" with different codes in this case?.

Comment: Try with str("đà nẵng", 'utf-8')

Comment: @Nether 1) that's not the problem 2) that will only decode if your terminal is UTF-8 or your code encoding is UTF-8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem you encounter is, that unicode allows multiple ways to compose the same symbol. The Python module `unicodedata` provides a function `normalize` that allows you to convert unicode representations to a fixed [form](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Norm_Forms)  (e.g. NFC)

```
from unicodedata import normalize

S1 = b'\xc4\x83\xcc\x83'.decode('UTF-8')
S2 = b'\xe1\xba\xb5'.decode('UTF-8')

print(normalize('NFC', S1).encode('UTF-8'))
print(normalize('NFC', S2).encode('UTF-8'))
```

In your example tripadvisor displayed in NFD form, while notepad used NFC.

Answer (score 3):

Although this is an old question, I will add an answer for anyone who stumbles across this question.

The difference between the two byte sequences is a case of canonical equivalence. Some characters can be represented by more than one byte sequence. For the letter ẵ, there are five canonically equivalent representations possible. In python, it is possible to use pyicu to get a list of all the canonical equivalences of a particular string.

Two of the five equate to the normalised forms using NFC and NFD. But in the example in this question, Firefox uses NFC for nẵng, the byte sequence is b'n\xe1\xba\xb5ng'.

But the byte sequence given from trip advisor is b'n\xc4\x83\xcc\x83ng`. This is not NFC, nor is it NFD. The NFD equivalent would be b'na\xcc\x86\xcc\x83ng'.

The string in trip Advisor was typed using Window's Vietnamese keyboard. When Microsoft first implemented a Vietnamese Unicode keyboard they followed the character model of Windows-1258, vowels with a circumflex, breve or hook were single precomposed characters, all tone markers were represented by combining diacritics, so resultant text at the time was a mix of precomposed and decomposed sequences. Neither NFC or NFD.

So in this instance, 'nẵng' was:

```
n 006E LATIN SMALL LETTER N
ă 0103 LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH BREVE
◌̃ 0303 COMBINING TILDE
n 006E LATIN SMALL LETTER N
g 0067 LATIN SMALL LETTER G
```

```
>>> s = 'nẵng'
>>> s.encode('UTF-8')
b'n\xc4\x83\xcc\x83ng'
>>> from unicodedata import normalize
>>> normalize("NFC", s).encode('UTF-8')
b'n\xe1\xba\xb5ng'
>>> normalize("NFD", s).encode('UTF-8')
b'na\xcc\x86\xcc\x83ng'
```