# Same word produces different Unicode normalization

Tags: python, unicode

**Problem:**
I have a Hebrew word `יֹשֵׁב` that I want to convert to its Unicode value.

Using Python, I get the byte string:

```
\u05d9\u05b9\u05e9\u05b5\u05c1\u05d1
```

However, using [this PHP website](https://www.online-toolz.com/tools/text-unicode-entities-convertor.php) I get the following sequence:

```
%u05D9%u05B9%uFB2A%u05B5%u05D1
```

(*if you copy from the word above from my post over to that website, you probably won't see this unicode and will see the same code that Python produces. I guess it is processed by stackoverflow before copying to that website*).

Py code:

```
str = 'יֹשֵׁב'
print(str.encode('ascii', 'backslashreplace'))
```

I can see that the difference being `שׁ` is encoded differently. Python sees `ש` and the dot separately and the website sees `שׁ` as one unit. **My question: Is there a way to get Python to produce the same result as that website does?**

**Steps taken:**
I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41975601/same-word-but-different-unicode-characters). I have tried the following codes, but they all produce the same result:

```
from unicodedata import normalize
S1 = 'יֹשֵׁב'
print(normalize('NFC', S1).encode('ascii', 'backslashreplace'))
print(normalize('NFD', S1).encode('ascii', 'backslashreplace'))
print(normalize('NFKC', S1).encode('ascii', 'backslashreplace'))
print(normalize('NFKD', S1).encode('ascii', 'backslashreplace'))
```

PS: I have no programming background. Learned Py myself. Pardon me if my question seems dumb.

Thank you very much!

Edit: the above message was typed in Safari. I've found out that Safari *may* twist the Unicode character value behind the Hebrew letter `שׁ` from `'\ufb2a'` to `'\u05e9\u05c1'`. But Chrome and Firefox (and possibly Edge) do not do the twist. So I'm now typing `שׁ` in Chrome to see if it twists or not.

Comment: Sidenote, avoid shadowing builtin names like `str`. [Here's an example issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31087111/4518341).

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know that. Will avoid using it in the future.

Comment: Now I can confirm that Safari twists the Unicode character value behind the Hebrew letter שׁ from '\ufb2a' to '\u05e9\u05c1'. Chrome does not do the twist. So it's character value remains '\ufb2a'.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [UAX#15](https://unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Primary_Exclusion_List_Table) of the Unicode standard, and that U+FA2B is on the [composition exclusion list](https://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/CompositionExclusions.txt), it seems that character can't be generated by normalization.  It can only be decomposed.  The Python normalization is correct.

If you want that specific representation, you can use Unicode escapes:

```
s = '\u05D9\u05B9\uFB2A\u05B5\u05D1'
```

or by name:

```
s = '\N{HEBREW LETTER YOD}\N{HEBREW POINT HOLAM}\N{HEBREW LETTER SHIN WITH SHIN DOT}\N{HEBREW POINT TSERE}\N{HEBREW LETTER BET}'
```

Comment: Thanks, @Mark Tolonen. But I want to get from שׁ to \uFB2A, not from \uFB2A to שׁ.

Comment: @Martin Unless your input method supports entering that specific character directly, you likely can’t.Unicode normalization rules don’t support it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're inputting the wrong version into Python. If it's in source code, it might be easier to use `\uXXXX` escapes instead of the Hebrew characters themselves. If not, I'm not sure where the problem would be; you'd need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](http:///help/minimal-reproducible-example).

But both normalize to the same thing under all normalization forms.

Here's proof:

```
from unicodedata import normalize

forms = ['NFC', 'NFD', 'NFKC', 'NFKD']
norms = set()
for s in '\ufb2a\u05b5', '\u05e9\u05b5\u05c1':
    print(ascii(s))
    norm = {ascii(normalize(form, s)) for form in forms}
    #print(norm)  # If you want to show each set
    norms.update(norm)

print('Normals:', *norms)
```

Output:

```
'\ufb2a\u05b5'
'\u05e9\u05b5\u05c1'
Normals: '\u05e9\u05b5\u05c1'
```

Comment: Hi @wjandrea, thanks a lot. After some other attempts, I think I have asked a wrong question.

Comment: Without the normalization, I can get what I want from Python. 
```
S1 = 'שׁ'
print(S1.encode('ascii', 'backslashreplace'))
```
My real-life case is that I use Keyboard Maestro to set a variable and then import its value to Python code. In this process, the שׁ letter was kind of "normalized". I get `b'\\u05e9\\u05c1'` instead of `b'\\ufb2a'`. If I type שׁ into the Python code directly, using the code I give above, I get the desired output: `b'\\ufb2a'`. So, I guess the real issue is not with Py

Comment: Somehow, either Keyboard Maestro decomposed the letter שׁ from `b'\\ufb2a'` to `b'\\u05e9\\u05c1'`, or the decomposition happened during the import via `os.environ`. `import os
S1 = os.environ['KMVAR_Local__Var']
print(S1.encode('ascii', 'backslashreplace'))`